# Positioning three divs: one left and two smaller stacked on the right

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, html, formatting

i'm using bootstrap and i wanna have one big div on the left side of my website and two smaller divs on the right side. The smaller divs should be under each other. The whole constructure shall look like an rectangle.

sorry for my bad english i hope you were able to understand me

Comment: Could you please further explain the layout of the smaller divs? "Under each other" doesn't make a lot of sense to me. If you can provide us with a picture of what you want, it would be great!

Answer (score 1):

Use a containing div to hold the two right divs and float both divs to the left.  The psuedo-selector "after" on .right-wrap will clear your floats semantically without the need for extra code.

Code:

```
<div class="left">Fu</div>
<div class="right-wrap">
<div class="rtop">blah</div>
<div class="rbottom">blah again</div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.left {
width: 100px;
height: 200px;
background:red;
float:left;
cleat:left;
}
.right-wrap {
width: 100px;
height: 200px;
float:left;
}
.right-wrap:after {
content: "";
clear:both;
}
.rtop {
position: relative;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background:blue;
}
.rbottom {
position: relative;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background:yellow;
}
```